# Sqlite database and datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I am trying to display my database(simple grades database) to wpf datagrid.Maybe someone know good example or simple code of connecting sqlite with datagrid?Also what is better:1.Manually create columns or use autogeneratecolumns? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used the following in one of my projects :

```
private void UpdateDataGrid(SQLiteConnection con, string sql)
{
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, con);
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

    dataGrid.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
}
```

Columns are generated automatically based on the query, if you want to preview all your table use the following : "SELECT * From TableName"

This worked perfectly in my winforms app, you might need to change a few things for it in WPF tho, I'm not sure.

Comment: Why the hell is this marked as an aswer the question quite clearly says WPF and WinForms is not WPF `you might need to change a few things for it in WPF tho` means nothing this does not work in WPF

Comment: In looking for an answer to this for WPF i came across the following: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/101266

Answer (score 0):

Here is video tutorial *SQLite database connection with WPF C#* :

[C# WPF Tutorial 3- SQLite database connection with WPF C# PART- 1/2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KfL0DgUdv0g)

[C# WPF Tutorial 4- SQLite database connection with WPF C# PART- 2/2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0f7Oa2JzRj0)

Look also this tutorial:

[WPF and SQLite Database](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/153407/WPF-and-SQLite-Database)